# Codigniter active record update query taking old where clause

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I have a following query

```
$this->db->set('registerStep', $param)
 ->where('id = ',$user_id)
 ->update($this->table_name);
```

Above Query is producing below sql code. even though I'm supplying only one where condition.

```
 UPDATE `users` SET `registerStep` = 2 WHERE `id` = 33 AND `id` = '165'
```

I think active record is using some cached where condition, is there any way I can free where condition.
 I tried using

```
$this->db->flush_cache();
```

But it's not helping.

Comment: Try a var_dump on $user_id to see what it is set to right before that line.

Comment: Why don't you try $this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('users', $param);

Comment: I tried `$this->db->where('id', $id); $this->db->update('users', $param);` but its not helping

Answer (score 3):

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#update

```
->where('id = ',$user_id)
```

is incorrect.

```
->where('id',$user_id)
```

is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fully correct. But I believe what you used a $this->db->where() before current query. Use the following code and you will see all the previously defined "where" statements:

```
print_r($this->db->ar_where);
$this->db->set('registerStep', $param)
     ->where('id = ',$user_id)
     ->update($this->table_name);
```