# Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, mysql-error-1052

I get this error and I can't figure out why?

> Error Number: 1052
>   Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

```
SELECT `leads`.*,
       `customers`.`id` AS customers_id,
       `customers`.`name` AS customers_name,
       `customers`.`company` AS customers_company,
       `customers`.`email` AS customers_email,
       `customers`.`phone` AS customers_phone,
       `customers`.`created_at` AS customers_created_at,
       `customers`.`updated_at` AS customers_updated_at,
       `customers`.`ip_address` AS customers_ip_addressFROM (`leads`)
JOIN `customers` ON `customers`.`id` = `leads`.`customer_id`
WHERE `id` = '3'
  AND `leads`.`id` = '1'LIMIT 1
```

> Filename: /home/www/REMOVED/models/lead.php
>
> Line Number: 12

The function looks like this:

```
function get($id)
{
  $this->db->select('leads.*, customers.id AS customers_id, customers.name AS customers_name, customers.company AS customers_company, customers.email AS customers_email, customers.phone AS customers_phone, customers.created_at AS customers_created_at, customers.updated_at AS customers_updated_at, customers.ip_address AS customers_ip_address');
  $this->db->where('leads.id', '1');
  $this->db->from('leads');
  $this->db->join('customers', 'customers.id = leads.customer_id');
  $this->db->limit(1);
  $query = $this->db->get();

  if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
  {
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result[0];
  }
}
```

And line 12 is `$query = $this->db->get();`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 32):

```
WHERE id = '3'
```

You don't specify which table the id field is coming from.  Did you mean:

```
WHERE customer.id = '3'
```

condition will be customer.id instead of id

Comment: I specify it in my code? $this->db->join('customers', 'customers.id = leads.customer_id');

Comment: thats the join clause - look at the WHERE clause in your SQL sample - its right there

Comment: But in my code I do specify the the table? $this->db->where('leads.id', '1');

Comment: Yeah, but as @Geoff Williams says, it appears that you have a `WHERE id = '3'` in your code, so, probably you'll have a `$this->db->where('id', 3)` somewhere in your code that is adding the WHERE is giving you the error

Comment: also, check @Mikhail answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379644/codigniter-active-record-update-query-taking-old-where-clause

Comment: This saved my hour :)