# How should I write an sql statement with conditional multiplication?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given I have a table like the following:

schedule

```
+-------+------------+--------+----------------+-------+---------+
| index | date       | empid  | dept           | sfrom | slength |
+-------+------------+--------+----------------+-------+---------+
|     0 | 09-24-2018 | 943023 | RADIOLOGY      | 03PM  |       8 |
|     1 | 09-24-2018 | 891046 | SURGERY        | 07AM  |       8 |
|     2 | 09-24-2018 | 878397 | RADIOLOGY      | 11PM  |       8 |
|     3 | 09-24-2018 | 886190 | CARDIOLOGY     | 03PM  |       8 |
|     4 | 09-24-2018 | 878397 | RADIOLOGY      | 11PM  |       8 |
|     5 | 09-24-2018 | 891330 | SURGERY        | 03PM  |       8 |
|     6 | 09-24-2018 | 995561 | SURGERY        | 11PM  |       8 |
|     7 | 09-24-2018 | 967577 | MATERNITY      | 03PM  |       8 |
|     8 | 09-24-2018 | 913891 | PEDIATRICS     | 03PM  |       8 |
|     9 | 09-24-2018 | 939148 | EMERGENCY      | 07AM  |       8 |
|    10 | 09-24-2018 | 995636 | RADIOLOGY      | 11PM  |       8 |
|    11 | 09-24-2018 | 995561 | EMERGENCY      | 11PM  |       8 |
|    12 | 09-24-2018 | 967577 | SURGERY        | 07AM  |       8 |
|    13 | 09-24-2018 | 883069 | INTENSIVE CARE | 07AM  |       8 |
|    14 | 09-24-2018 | 951876 | ONCOLOGY       | 03PM  |       8 |
|    15 | 09-24-2018 | 884866 | CARDIOLOGY     | 07AM  |       8 |
|    16 | 09-24-2018 | 864425 | ONCOLOGY       | 03PM  |       8 |
```

employee table

```
+-------+--------+------------+-----------+---------+----------------+----------------+------+
| index | empid  | lastName   | firstName | emptype | cellphone      | homephone      | ftpt |
+-------+--------+------------+-----------+---------+----------------+----------------+------+
|     0 | 919675 | Cermak     | Vern      | LPN     | (138)7198-0862 | (655)2249-9926 | FT   |
|     1 | 906704 | Paille     | Lorilee   | NULL    | (858)1100-2722 | (377)1506-1986 | PT   |
|     2 | 900486 | Ober       | Shalanda  | NULL    | (210)1508-8132 | (820)1612-0197 | FT   |
|     3 | 883367 | Clyburn    | Jeffry    | LPN     | (420)7798-7220 | (476)7661-3070 | FT   |
|     4 | 953807 | Quarles    | Timmy     | LPN     | (513)2756-9892
```

if I have to calculate the total cost per dept per employee type and per shift, how should I do this in sql ?

> Given that if a shift includes midnight I multiply my wage by 25% ?

I have a sample output as follows but no clue how to do this ?:

```
+------------+---------------+----------------+---------+
| DEPARTMENT | EMPLOYEE_TYPE |     SHIFT      |  COST   |
+------------+---------------+----------------+---------+
| Anesthesia | LPN           |    7 AM –3     | $24,567 |
| Anesthesia | LPN           |    3 PM –11PM  | $18,546 |
| Anesthesia | LPN           |    11 PM –7AM  | $22,874 |
| Anesthesia | NA            |    7 AM –3 PM  | $9,764  |
| Anesthesia | NA            |    3 PM –11 PM | $10,287 |
| Anesthesia | NA            |    11 PM –7 AM | $6, 875 |
| Anesthesia | RN            |    7 AM –3 PM  | $33,123 |
+------------+---------------+----------------+---------+
```

This is my sql statement until now: 
But how should I get this to work ?
EDIT1:

```
 Select 
      t1.dept,
      t2.emptype,
      t1.sfrom,
      t1.slength,
      SUM(t1.slength) as hours 
      CASE WHEN CAST(STR_TO_DATE(sfrom,'%h%p') + 
                     STR_TO_DATE(slength,'%H')) > STR_TO_DATE(23,'%H') 
      then (slength*10*1.25) else (slength*10) end as cost 
 from 
      schedule_2 as t1 
      Join (select 
                empid,
                emptype 
            from 
                employees_2) as t2 ON t1.empid=t2.empid 
 GROUP BY 
       dept,
       emptype,
       slength;
```

EDIT2:

```
Select 
    t1.dept,
    t2.emptype,
    t1.sfrom,
    t1.slength,
    SUM(t1.slength) as hours
    CASE WHEN HOUR(STR_TO_DATE(sfrom,'%h%p') + 
                   STR_TO_DATE(slength,'%H')) > 23 
    then (slength*10*1.25) else (slength*10) 
from 
    schedule_2 as t1 
    Join (select 
               empid,
               emptype 
          from` 
               employees_2) as t2 ON t1.empid=t2.empid 
 GROUP BY 
      dept,
      emptype,
      slength;
```

I am getting the following error but can't seem to figure out why ?

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CASE WHEN HOUR(STR_TO_DATE(sfrom,'%h%p') +
>   STR_TO_DATE(slength,'%H')) > 23 then ' at line 2

Comment: Have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Comment: yes I am i trying to connect the two tables together, and then do a group by, but still unable to execute it. Im new to sql :/

Comment: Can you include your query too?

Comment: Where are the wage, or price per hour? I don't see it on any table...

Comment: wage is arbitrary, any value such as 10$/hour works. I wanted to understand how the sql statement worked

Comment: You just miss commas near in your `case` statement.. And when make query make your query readable.. It will help you find typo or missing.. And of course for beauty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use case clause in your sql statement for the cost field. Like for eg:

```
case when <<your clause for night shift>> then (slength*10)+(0.25*10*slength)
else (slength*10) end as cost
```

Assuming that it is 10$ per hour. You can put night shift condition as per your business rules.

Comment: can you show the entire sql query if the shift time is a string column ?

Comment: what time do you consider for midnight hours? Secondly does shift start hourly like 1 AM , 2AM etc?

Comment: 12:00am is the midnight hour, and shifts can start at anytime, but if they end at 12:00 am or later then 1.2 times is the cost.

Comment: Put comma(,) after SUM(t1.slength) as hours

Comment: What is the name of your table...schedule or schedule_2? Secondly you are not giving end clause after  else (slength*10) 
Refer the way I have given case clause

Comment: its actually named schedule_2

Comment: Try putting end after  else (slength*10)

Comment: @Ryan see my comment on top and accept my review.. It will be easier to see when you have readable query..

Comment: Hey figured it out with the error, just one last thing. Wouldn't we be using "hours" as the multiplier for cost ?

Comment: As per my understanding slength field denotes number of hours a person will be in shift ...that you need to figure out as per the database design and business logic...conditional stuff seems to be sorted out :)